# Trouble Configuring Tracing Application Insights in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-application-insights

I created a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application in Visual Studio 2017 which results in a Razor Pages implementation.

In my **Index.cshtml.cs** file, I implemented this:

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Trace.TraceError("*************** INDEX ERROR ***************");
        Trace.TraceWarning("*************** INDEX WARNING ***************");
        Trace.TraceInformation("*************** INDEX INFORMATION ***************");
        Trace.WriteLine("*************** INDEX WRITELINE ***************");

        var telemetry = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient();
        telemetry.TrackTrace("*************** INDEX TRACKTRACE ***************");
    }
```

I did all of the configuration to my Application Insights instance.

**appsettings.json**

"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace"
    }
  },

**appsettings.Development.json**

"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }

When I run my page and watch the Log streams page, I can see the telemetry.TrackTrace entries, but not the Trace.Trace* entries.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Application Insights SDK for Asp.Net Core, it can collect only traces sent using [ILogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#how-to-create-logs) mechanism. Please follow instructions here if you are headed this route:
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Logging

But it seems like you are logging using System.Diagnostics.Trace methods. Application Insights can capture these, but it require installation of additional nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener/2.6.0-beta3), the latest beta of which support .net core apps.